# $dq_{rev}$ and $dq$, which one is larger?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy, physical-chemistry, reversibility

Im learning about entropy and some concepts makes me confusing.
For a reversible and irreversible process with a same initial state and final state, it is said that entropy change of a system is calculated by $dq_{rev}/T$ for both processes because entropy is a state function.

But for the entropy change of a surrounding, reversible process is calculated as the negative of the system, while for irreversible process it is not. For a entropy of universe to increase, doesn't the entropy change for the surrounding of irreversible process has to be larger than reversible process? therefore dq_sur,irr has to be larger than dq_sur,rev? I don't understand why it is the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an irreversible process, to get the entropy change of both the system and the surroundings, you must first separate the system from the surroundings.  You must then devise a new reversible process for the system, using a new set of surroundings that are capable of taking the system between the same original two end states reversibly.  And you must devise a new (different) reversible process for the surroundings, using a new system that is capable of taking the surroundings between the same original end states reversibly.  So you have the original system with new surroundings and the original surroundings with a new system.  You then calculate the integral of dq/T for each of these two alternate reversible processes.  These will be the changes in entropy of the system and of the surroundings for the original irreversible process.

Typically, the surroundings will make use of an ideal constant temperature reservoir.  It will consist of an incompressible liquid with enormous heat capacity so that its temperature cannot change significantly.  For such a reservoir, the first law tells us that $$\Delta U_{reservoir}=-q_{system, irreversible}$$Furthermore, since the two end states are the same in the reversible and irreversible process for the reservoir, we must also have that $$\Delta S_{reservoir}=\frac{\Delta U_{reservoir}}{T_{reservoir}}=-\frac{q_{irreversible}}{T_{reservoir}}$$

Answer (score 0):

> But for the entropy change of a surrounding, reversible process is
> calculated as the negative of the system, while for irreversible
> process it is not.

It is better to say for a reversible process the total entropy change (system + surroundings) is zero whereas for an irreversible process the total entropy change is greater than zero.  (See example below for an irreversible adiabatic process)

> For a entropy of universe to increase, doesn't the entropy change for
> the surrounding of irreversible process has to be larger than
> reversible process?

No.

For example, in the case of an irreversible adiabatic process the entropy change of the surroundings is zero because there is no heat transfer, whereas the entropy change of the system is positive as entropy is generated in the system due to the irreversible work. The entropy change of the universe (system + surroundings) is greater than zero.

> therefore $dq_{sur,irr}$ has to be larger than $dq_{sur,rev}$? I don't
> understand why it is the opposite.

Regardless of whether the process is reversible or irreversible, if it involves heat transfer between the system and surroundings the heat lost/gained by one equals the heat gained/lost by the other, for conservation of energy. The difference it it is the total change in entropy (system +surroundings) that is greater than zero in the case of an irreversible heat transfer.

The simplest example involves an irreversible heat transfer of $Q$ between two thermal reservoirs. A thermal reservoir has a great enough heat capacity such that its temperature does not change for a given transfer of heat. Consider one reservoir to be the surroundings with temperature $T_{surr}$ and the other the system with temperature $T_{sys}$ such that  $T_{surr}\gt T_{surr}$. The total entropy change is

$$\Delta S_{univ}=\Delta S_{surr}+\Delta S_{sys}=\frac{-Q}{T_{surr}}+\frac{Q}{T_{sys}}$$

Note the following:

1. Since $T_{surr}\gt T_{sys}$, then $\Delta S_{univ}\gt 0$.
2. However, note that there is a decrease not increase in entropy of the surroundings while the entropy of the system increases.
3. If the heat transfer were in the other direction (i.e., $T_{sys}\gt T_{surr}$), the total increase will still be greater than zero, except this time the entropy of the surroundings increases while that of the system decreases.
4. As the two temperatures approach one another the overall entropy increase decreases becoming zero when they are equal and the process is reversible.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you consider an irreversible process then the Clausius inequality states that $d q_{rev} + d q_{surr} > 0$.
Thus we can conclude that $d q_{rev} > - \left( d q_{surr} \right)$. We cannot directly conclude anything about the values of $d q_{rev}$ and $d q_{surr}$ .

For instance take some hypothetical examples.

1. $d q_{rev} = 10 ~ J$ and $d q_{irrev} = 15 ~ J \implies d q_{rev} + d q_{irrev} > 0$

This process will be spontaneous despite $d q_{irrev}$ being greater than $d q_{rev}$.

2. $d q_{rev} = 10 ~ J$ and $d q_{irrev} = -5 ~ J \implies d q_{rev} + d q_{irrev} > 0$

This process is clearly spontaneous but here $d q_{irrev} < d q_{rev}$

3. $d q_{rev} = 10 ~ J$ and $d q_{irrev} = -15 ~ J \implies d q_{rev} + d q_{irrev} < 0$

This process is not spontaneous.

But if you observe in processes 1) and 2) :

$d q_{rev} > - \left( d q_{irrev} \right)$ which is the Clausius Inequality.